# RIA Services and Relationships in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, ado.net, entity-relationship, wcf-ria-services

I've finally managed to get a handle on loading information using Silverlight, ADO.NET Entities, and RIA Services, but I'm still having a problem with getting the information about the relationships.

For instance, imagine a product, and that product has several categories of attributes. We'll call them ProductAreas.

The Product object has a property called ProductAreas (as a result of their relationship), but when I call:

```
ctx.Load(GetProductsQuery());
```

(Where ctx is my DomainContext), the Product objects returned have the ProductAreas property, but it contains no elements, which is a very serious problem, in my case.

So the question is: How do I get access to these relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your `GetProductsQuery()` method does, but you should be able use the `.Include('ProductAreas')` method in your query. If you update your question with the contents of that method I'll try to help more.

Comment: Thanks, Ben! This is great. You led me exactly where I needed to go. I elaborated on your answer a little below, as just adding the include didn't haul in the information, but that in conjunction with the include attribute did.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't technically the way this system is supposed to work, but I wanted to expand on your answer, while at the same time giving it the credit it rightfully deserves for leading me where I needed to be.

The solutions was to, in the GetProductsQuery() method use

```
return this.ObjectContext.Products.Include("ProductAreas");
```

instead of

```
return this.ObjectContext.Products;
```

And in the metadata file, go to the Products class and, just above the ProductAreas property add [Include()], so that it looks like:

```
[Include()]
public EntityCollection<ProductAreas> ProductAreas;
```